# PHP get available bytes from Socket

Tags: php, sockets

So I've been writing this tool and I am using these [Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) (not [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)) and the difference with them I surmise that the second uses strictly stream-based sockets. The thing is that you can't use [socket_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php) on the sockets I am using.

Is there any other way to get the amount of available bytes besides [socket_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streams returned from `fsockopen()` are a managed wrapper around regular sockets; the unread bytes (which is what you're probably after) is the difference between the `read()` on the socket (made by the wrapper itself) and the `fread()` on the wrapper (made by your script).

The wrapper reads in chunks of 8192 bytes, but the `fread()` or `fgets()` may not read all data at once, which is why there's an `unread` meta data field you could query; whether that's useful is another thing ;-)

When using regular sockets, you could either:

- use `socket_select()` to wait for data to become available, followed by a suitably large `socket_read()`
- use `socket_set_nonblock()` to make the socket unblocked and attempt to read from it